# How to add same ViewModifier to multiple Views and Controls using extensions

Tags: swiftui

If I have this ViewModifier.

```
struct AppFont: ViewModifier {
var size: Int?
func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content.font(Font.custom("Futura", size: CGFloat(size ?? 15)))
}
```

}

From that I create an extension one for Text and one for Textfield

```
 extension Text {
    func customFont(size : Int) ->  some View {
        return ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: AppFont(size: size))
    }
}

extension TextField {
     func customFont(size : Int) ->  some View {
           return ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: AppFont(size: size))
       }
}
```

How can I add this extension to Text, Textfield and Button without repeating the code? So I could use Text("hello").customFont() TextField(...).customFont() or Button().customFont()

Answer (score 1):

There is not really anything to gain by wrapping the font in a custom ViewModifier and then again using it in an extension. I think the best solution is to have an extension on Text separately to have the return type be Text so you can apply other text-specific modifiers to it. You can also have an extension on View that will cover all other scenarios.

```
extension Text {

    func customFont(size : Int = 15) -> Text {

        return self.font(Font.custom("Futura",
                                     size: CGFloat(size)))
    }
}

extension View {

    func customFont(size : Int = 15) -> some View {

        return self.font(Font.custom("Futura",
                                     size: CGFloat(size)))
    }
}
```